# Duda sobre una animación input-label

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero replicar esta animación que consiste en, cuando el input esta onfocus, su respectivo label (que graficamente está dentro del input) se eleve a la parte superior del input, dejando espacio al usuario para poder ver que está ingresando, y al hacer click fuera del input o al pasar al siguiente input, si no tiene nada escrito en el, el label baje.

Lo que llegué a hacer es que el label se eleve al clickear en el input, pero al sacar el "focus" del input el efecto no se revierte, el label se queda arriba hasta que vuelves a hacer click en el input.

HTML:

```
<div class="grupoLI">
    <label for="" id="label1">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="input1">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var label1 = document.getElementById('label1');
var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');

input1.addEventListener('onfocus', (e) => {
  if(input1.value === "") {
    label1.classList.toggle("inputSeleccionado");
  }
});
```

Si a alguien le sirve ver el codigo completo: https://codepen.io/TCassas/pen/oNNdZLe

Comment: Pon también el CSS que estás usando y si lo metes todo en un snippet podremos ver el código funcionando

Comment: Podrías echarle un vistazo a este componente de material web https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/text-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás usando la propiedad `onfocus` en lugar del evento `focus` por lo que ni siquiera puede estar funcionando tu ejemplo.
Por otra parte ahí lo que haces es quitar o añadir una clase cada vez que el elemento coge el foco siempre que el `input` este vacío pero deberías añadir la clase cuando tenga el foco y quitarla al perderlo con el evento `blur`.

Pongo un ejemplo en el que el `label` cambia de color cuando el `input` coge el foco y lo quita cuando lo pierde solo si esta vacío:

```js
var label1 = document.getElementById("label1");
var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");

input1.addEventListener("focus", e => {
  if (input1.value === "") {
    label1.classList.add("inputSeleccionado");
  }
});
input1.addEventListener("blur", e => {
  if (input1.value === "") {
    label1.classList.remove("inputSeleccionado");
  }
});
```

```css
.inputSeleccionado {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grupoLI" id="xD">
  <label for="" id="label1">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="input1">
</div>
```

Comment: Listo, funciona tal como quería, ¡muchas gracias!